# Connecting to a server on a local network via static IP

Tags: networking, router, static-ip

I have a server at home. I also have a contract with a static IP address. I want to make it possible for every device in my network to gain Internet access. I also want to remote control my server, which means that all traffic to the static IP address should be redirected to my server.

Right now if I connect via browser to my static IP, I come to the RPD Router configuration page.

I build the network like this:

FritzBox (working as modem with static IP)
RPD Router (working as a normal router)

I already tried setting up DMZ to the local address from the server, and also redirecting ports to the server.

[image]

Comment: Consider adding an actual diagram e.g. using [draw.io](https://draw.io) to make your setup clear and also include some configuration details like interfaces and what kind of network addresses you would find on which interface. What didn't work about your approaches?

Comment: Made it :) @Seth

Answer (score 1):

To permit incoming connections to be forwarded to your server, you need to do the following:

1. Configure your modem to use *[bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridging_(networking)) mode*. In this mode it stops operating at [OSI layer 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_layer) and instead passes all traffic [directly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_link_layer) to your router. As a result, the modem will no longer be assigned your static IP. Instead you will...
2. Assign your static IP to your router's WAN (Internet) interface.

Now all inbound connections from the Internet will hit your router directly, where you can configure the appropriate port-forwarding rules to direct traffic to your internal server.

Comment: i will test that now :)

Comment: i tried it now after long research and kind of unlocking a special feature on the fritzbox i got it but, the router 2 has no connection to the internet anymore.

Comment: You need to manually configure your static IP, subnetmask, and gateway on the router. Have you done that?

Comment: Yeah i done that.. @Twisty

Comment: Hmmm, sounds like the bridge mode isn't working on the Fritz box.

Comment: so the only way to achieve my goal is a new fritzbox?

Comment: That's a little hard for me to determine. But if you're confident you have properly configured it for bridge mode and it's not working, then yes, replacement may be necessary.